# What is the difference between the range function and range keyword?

Tags: function, go, range, keyword

What is the difference between the range function and range keyword in Go?

```
func main(){
     s := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}

     for i,j:= range s{
         fmt.Printf("%d => ",i)
         fmt.Println(j) 
     }
 }
```

different with

```
  func main(){
        s := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}

        for i,j:= range(s){
            fmt.Printf("%d => ",i)
            fmt.Println(j)  
         }
   }
```

Comment: There's no difference in how they'd be compiled, but gofmt will remove the unnecessary parentheses -- you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Why do you ask? There is no difference.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `range` function in Go. There is only the [`range` keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords).

What's confusing you is the optional parenthesis in your second example. These parenthesis are, as mentioned, **optional**, so the [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) tool will remove them.

But there is no difference between `range x` and `range(x)`.